# click/drag to draw several lines simultaneously on canvas with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-canvas

I am interested in having the user click and draw a right triangle on a canvas element, but when I call my drawLine function the second time, the first one gets deleted.  Example diagram here: [right_triangle_draw](https://s3.amazonaws.com/ultrasoundoftheweek.com/uf_quiz/lines.jpg) What gives?

```
  $("canvas").mousedown(function(event) {
      var totalOffsetX = 0;
      var totalOffsetY = 0;
      var canvasX = 0;
      var canvasY = 0;
      var currentElement = this;

      do {
          totalOffsetX += currentElement.offsetLeft - currentElement.scrollLeft;
          totalOffsetY += currentElement.offsetTop - currentElement.scrollTop;
      }
      while (currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent)

      startX = event.pageX - totalOffsetX;
      startY = event.pageY - totalOffsetY;

      $(this).bind('mousemove', function(e) {
          var xdiff = Math.abs(startX - e.pageX + totalOffsetX);
          var ydiff = Math.abs(startY - e.pageY + totalOffsetY);

          drawLine(startX, startY, e.pageX - totalOffsetX, e.pageY - totalOffsetY, direction);

          drawLine(startX, startY, e.pageX - totalOffsetX, startY, direction);

      });
  }).mouseup(function() {
      $(this).unbind('mousemove');
  });



  function drawLine(x, y, stopX, stopY, direction) {
          ctx.strokeStyle = 'rgba(0,155,205,0.8)';
          ctx.lineWidth = 3;
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height);
          ctx.beginPath();
          ctx.moveTo(x, y);
          ctx.lineTo(stopX, stopY);
          ctx.closePath();
          ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are clearing the canvas each time you draw a line. Try using ctx.clearRect(0, 0, can.width, can.height); before the drawLine calls, on the mouseMove function and remove it from drawLine.

Comment: perfect!  works well.  thanks for the advice.  if I could up vote I would.